# MVC Routing parameters with Hyphen

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, routes, asp.net-mvc-routing

We are rebuilding an old website to a new MVC Website, and i would like to redirect the old url's to new url's.

the old url's are build like this `/p-{productid}-{productname}.aspx` 
but it is possible that the productname parameter also contains hyphens. so the url could be `/p-123-product-name.aspx`.

If i add this rule to the mvc RouteCollection, the first parameter values will be:

productid = 123-product

productname = name

is there a way to make the productid parameter 'not greedy'?

Answer (score 0):

You can add a constraint to your route, and use a regex to specify the id. Assuming you are going to a controller called 'products', and the view is called ShowProdcut and the id contains 3 or more numbers your route might look like this:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Products",
        defaults: new {controller = "Products", action = "ShowProduct"},
        url: "Products/p-{productId}-{productName}",
        constraints: new {productId= @"\d{3,}"}
    );
}
```

obviously if your id's are more complicated you will need a different Regex.